# How do I use dashes ("-") in a swift date string?

Tags: ios, swift, date-formatting, dateformatter

I'd like the date, Monday 12/9/2019 4:22 PM, to be displayed as "Monday - December 9 - 2019, 4:22 PM".

I tried:

```
private func getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp timestamp: Int) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp/1000))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = .current
    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE '-' MMMM d '-' yyyy',' h:mm a")

    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

print(getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp: 1575926532472))
// prints: Monday, December 9, 2019, 4:22 PM
```

Resources
[Unicode Technical Standard - PART 4: DATES](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)
[DateFormatter - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `formatter.dateFormat = "..."` instead of using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` ?

Comment: `h:mm a` won't really work with `.current` locale. System settings can overwrite it to 24h time.

Comment: Andrew, when users have specified a preference for 24 hour clock or to have the day of the month before the month, do you *really* want to show them a date in this format, which will feel very alien to them? Generally we want to respect their preferences. Or would you like to show them the date in their preferred format, only replacing commas with dashes?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. @Rob, that's a good question! This format is a request from my designer. But you're right, it should be localized too. Is there a way to respect each user's preferences, while preserving dashes across all locales?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `dateFormat` instead of using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` like so:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE - MMMM d - yyyy, h:mm a"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide what the various formats for different locales are. You don’t, IMHO, want `"EEEE '-' MMMM d '-' yyyy',' h:mm a"`, because in Europe, they use 24 hour clock and want the day before the month.

I would encourage you to try the standard date/time layout in your UI, e.g., simply:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .full
formatter.timeStyle = .short
```

Then, the US user will see:

> Tuesday, December 31, 2019 at 9:49 PM

The UK user will see:

> Tuesday, 31 December 2019 at 21:49

And your French user will see:

> mardi 31 décembre 2019 à 21:49

But, let’s assume for a second, that I won’t be able to convince your designer to adopt well established conventions. So, how would you handle the inconsistent use of commas and the use of the “at” preposition? Perhaps

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")

let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
timeFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: ", ", with: " - ")

let timeString = timeFormatter.string(from: date)

let result = dateString + ", " + timeString
```

This is non-standard, but accomplishes what the designer was looking for, while still localizing the solution.

Then, the US user will see:

> Tuesday - December 31 - 2019, 9:49 PM

The UK user will see:

> Tuesday - 31 December 2019, 21:49

And your French user will see:

> mardi 31 décembre 2019, 21:49

While I get your designer was undoubtedly looking for something unique, I think this just detracts from the UI. I’d vote for sticking with established conventions for date/time strings.

---

By the way, if you decide to build your own date formatter strings, I’d suggest you use `j:mma` instead of `h:mma`. At the very least, you want to have the hour respect the user’s preference of 12 v 24 hour clock. For example,

```
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEEdMMMMyyyyj:mma")
```

Comment: Great answer Rob! Since DrewG20 solved my specific problem and you helped me realize a more generic solution, would you copy your answer to a new question ("How do I use dashes (“-”) in a **localized** swift date string?") and I'll accept it there? This way, future users can benefit from correct answers to two distinct questions!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set using `dateFormat` as your updated code you can use as follow:

```
private func getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp timestamp: Int) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp/1000))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = .current
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE - MMMM d - yyyy, h:mm a"

    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

print(getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp: 1575926532472))
// prints: Monday - December 9 - 2019, 4:22 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private func getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp timestamp: Int) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp/1000))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE - MMMM d - yyyy, h:mm a"
    let result = formatter.string(from: date)
    return result
}

print(getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp: 1575926532472))
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this two arguments :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter
The first arguments is teach you how to create the Date.The second arguments is teach you how to create the format for Date.These two things may be your are correct. But there are principal in macOS 10.12 and later or iOS 10 and later. The format must use the ISO8601DateFormatter class when working with ISO 8601 date representations. So your format is correct or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private func getLastUpdatedString(forTimestamp timestamp: Int) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp/1000))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = .current
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE - MMMM d - yyyy, h:mm a"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```